# How to populate a generated Column in a DataGridView efficiently?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I have a DataGridView setup in my Winforms program with information populated from a database.

I've populated the DataGridView using `Select * FROM [Data]` with the following code:

```
private void GetData(string selectCommand)
{
    try
    {
        // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, strConn);

        // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
        // delete commands based on selectCommand.
        OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
        DataTable table = new DataTable
        {
            Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        };
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

        // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
        LogDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
    }
    catch (OleDbException) { }
}
```

Comment: We don't know enough about your data source.  Can you left join the status information?

Comment: @LarsTech I've edited the post and added some more code. I think left join would work, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could directly cross-JOIN two databases in the same query and generate a single DataTable which already includes the Status, if that's possible. Meaning, if the database where the Status information is stored is not updated by some other process independently. Otherwise, you have to poll it. If you have to poll it, you just need to update a Field of the DataTable used as the DataSoure of the DGV. It will update the UI immediately.

Comment: @Jimi I think this is exactly what I need in my query, my second access database has the SO nr and another column that includes statuses. Could you give me an example of how I would be able to cross join the two tables based on the "SO nr" being shared between them two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**:

If the database where the Status information is stored is not constantly updated by some other process, you can simply specify that the column to join is part of a table in an external database.

If it instead receives updates from other sources, you'll have to poll it with a Timer (or use the FileSystemWatcher class to receive notifications when the database file changes). The query is the same, though.

Add **`[;database=Second database Path].[Source Table] AS alias`** after the JOIN clause, then proceed as usual.

For example, set a DataGridView.Datasource specifying the second database path.

```
LogDataGridView.DataSource = GetCrossJoinedTable([Second database path]);
```

The connection string's `Data Source=` contains the path to the first database.
Then, cross-join two Tables in the two databases using a common key and return the column which contains the Status information from the Table in the second database (the `[Order Status]` column, if I read correctly the updated code).

```
private DataTable GetCrossJoinedTable(string secondDataBasePath)
{
    var dt = new DataTable("JoinedTable");
    string sql = "SELECT [Data].*, status.[Order Status] " +
                $"FROM [Data] LEFT JOIN [;database={secondDataBasePath}].[Output] AS status " +
                 "ON [Data].[SO nr] = status.[Source No]";
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=firstDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;"))
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            dt.Load(reader);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**:
Query the first database, add a Status Column, update the Status info from the second database then poll new Status information with a Timer.

You can call `LogDataGridView.DataSource = GetMainTableData()` to set the datasource. It will also load the Status information from the second database.

The Timer will then poll only the second database, to check whether the `[Order Status]` of a matching `[SO nr]` Column in the DataTable has changed.
When the DataTable (here, a field named `mainDT`) is updated, your DataGraidView will reflect immediately the change.

- If the data can be edited, the Timer should skip the update if [IsCurrentCellInEditMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentcellineditmode) returns `true` (read the notes there, about CheckBoxColumns), or paused while a Cell is in edit mode ([CellBeginEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit) event) and reumed when the Cell exits edit mode ([CellEndEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit) event).
- Remember to stop and dispose of the Timer when the Form closes (`Form.FormClosing` event).

If you don't need a Timer to poll the Status info, just call `UpdateStatusInfo()` whenever you need to update the DGV.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer sqlTimer = null;
DataTable mainDT = new DataTable("MainTable");

private DataTable GetMainTableData()
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Data";
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=firstDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;"))
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)) {
        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        mainDT.Load(reader);
        mainDT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() {
            Caption = "Status", ColumnName = "fStatus", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true
        });
    }
    sqlTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 5000 };
    sqlTimer.Tick += (s, ev) => { UpdateStatusInfo(mainDT, false); };
    sqlTimer.Start();
    return UpdateStatusInfo(mainDT, true);
}

private DataTable UpdateStatusInfo(DataTable dt, bool returnTable)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Output.[Order Status], Output.[Source No] FROM Output";
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=secondDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;"))
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)) {
        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Columns["fStatus"].ReadOnly = false;
        while (reader.Read()) {
            dt.Select($"fNumber = {reader["Source No"]}").FirstOrDefault()?
              .SetField("fStatus", reader["Order Status"].ToString());
        }
        dt.Columns["fStatus"].ReadOnly = true;
        return returnTable ? dt : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The first method seems to work though takes some time to run.

Option 1: How would I refresh the entire table if I wanted to check for new updates to status?

Option 2: This doesn't seem to work and just shows me an empty data-table. Which is why I'm getting a System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).' when calling UpdateStatusInfo

Comment: 1) Both methods are tested and working. 2) 3You need to adapt both to your actual connection and provider types (here, I used `ACE.OLEDB.12`, but you may have to change that)) 3) The first is slow: it can be slow if the databases are in different *locations*; more specifically, if one of them is on a remote or removable drive. Of course the number of records counts. My test databases, positioned in the same folder, contain both ~`1k` records: the query takes ~`4-6ms` to complete.

Comment: 4) The second method simply copies a string value from a field to another. If you have an exception, then you did something wrong. E.g., the field name is not the same, the data type is not the same etc. But, since the exception is `0x80004005`, you're probably using the same `ACE.OLEDB.12` provider I used here, when you actually don't have it or its bitness is not the same as your app's. Don't use the connection string I used here, use the one you already had. If you still have some kind of issue, then post the modified code. I cannot debug thin air.

Comment: My databases are both on a network drive. I'm using an .mdb file for my database which are using Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; and have followed your code completely using LogDataGridView.DataSource = GetMainTableData(); to set the data source. The error I get is on the var reader = command.ExecuteReader(). The same connection string seems to work fine on the Option 1

Comment: If you have 2 mdb files on a network drive (using an ancient history format and ancient history provider, `Jet.OLEDB.4.0`) you cannot expect it to be fast. If you have an exception using the second sample code, then you made a mistake somewhere. As already mentioned, if I cannot see what code you implemented and how (connection string included), I cannot help you.

Comment: Jimi, I've updated my code to show you what I've added. Thank you again

Comment: There are two `var reader = command.ExecuteReader()`, one for each connection. Which one generates an error and what error, exactly? I just tested it with `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` (which also implies that I had to set `Prefer 32-bit` in the Project's Build options) and everything works fine (though slower) with this provider, too. See that you don't have opened one of the databases in exclusive mode somewhere else. Try the same code moving the files to a local folder. Also, verify that the field names are correct.

Comment: [Sample results using MS Access to edit values in real time](https://imgur.com/ga2WdZy). With the Timer.Interval is set to `3000ms`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do :

1/ You create a DataTable variable from your OUTPUT table (eg. OutputDataTable)

2/ In your method `private void GetData(string selectCommand)`, before setting datasource (`bindingSource1.DataSource = table;`), you suscribe an event RowsAdded ( `dataGridView1.RowsAdded += this.DataGridView1_RowsAdded;`).
In the event you do something like :

```
    private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        string valueToFind = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["SO nr"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        var row = OutputDataTable.Select($"Source No" = '{valueToFind}'").First();
        string status = row["Order Status"].ToString();
        dataGridView1[dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["Status"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value = status;
    }
```